# php unable to connect to mysql in wamp

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I have installed a wamp and am trying to connect to mysql but I keep receiving  warnings as described in the image. The php code is the one just below here. Any help?

```
   <?php
    $serverName="localhost:81";
    $userName="root";
     $password="";
     $con= mysqli_connect($serverName,$userName,$password);
   if($con) echo 'Connected';

  ?>
```

[image: warning message received]

Comment: Please explain why you got mysql running on port 81?

Comment: port 80 is used by IIS

Comment: mysql would be 3306 not 81...

Comment: Try just, `$serverName="localhost";`

Comment: Thank you so much....it worked!!!!!!!You made my day...

Comment: change to just localhost and port 3306 in both cases it finally worked!

Comment: glad to help :/ fyi: its because mysql runs on port 3306 by default, and if the port not passed it will choose that port internally.